# How to tablesort the ajex result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tablesorter

The ajax is working. am able to populate the table with data from the Api

```js
function searchcovid() {
  var country = document.querySelector('#country').value

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/{{ Config::get('
    chatter.routes.home ') }}/covid/searchcovid',
    data: {
      'searchcountry': country
    },
    success: function(results) {
      if (results == 0)
        alert('0');
      else
        var resultData = JSON.parse(results).locations;
      console.log(resultData);
      var bodyData = '';
      $.each(resultData, function(index, row) {
        bodyData += '<tr>';
        //bodyData+='<td>'+row.country+'</td>';//
        bodyData += '<td>' + row.province + '</td>';
        bodyData += '<td>' + row.latest.confirmed + '</td>';
        bodyData += '<td>' + row.latest.deaths + '</td>';
        bodyData += '<td>' + row.latest.recovered + '</td>';
        bodyData += '</tr>';
      })
      $("#bodyData").html(bodyData);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="covid" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="margin-top:30px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Province/Region</th>
      <th>Confirmed Case</th>
      <th>Death</th>
      <th>Recovered</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodyData"></tbody>
</table>
```

got difficulties to make the result sortable by tablesorter. Your help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't see a single line of code that would indicate something about table sorting. Your whole JS code has nothing to do with it, So what table sorter are you talking about?

Comment: <!-- Tablesorter-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.blue.css">
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#covid").tablesorter({
      sortList: [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0]],
   theme: "blue",
   widgets: ["zebra"],
   widgetOptions : {
     zebra : [ "normal-row", "alt-row" ]
   }
    });
 }
);

</script>

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67140970/edit) the question to include all info an code. Larger code blocks gets unreadable in comments. I also don't see why this is tagged with PHP when the question is 100% js?

Comment: I created a fiddle for you, edit it and put only relevant JS code inside it. I believe we dont need any of the ajax, and please populate table with dummy data. Also visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to make https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example